# Bluetooth keyboard doesn't work on Mojave

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, bluetooth, mojave

I have a MacBook Pro 2017 and ever since I installed macOS Mojave, my Bluetooth keyboard stopped working properly.

I don't have a stock Apple Bluetooth keyboard, I have this one: https://www.gearbest.com/ipad-keyboards/pp_576049.html

It worked completely fine in High Sierra but ever since I upgraded to Mojave, the keyboard just doesn't work most of the times.

I don't have any problem with pairing with the keyboard, whenever macOS asks me to enter 6 digits and then press enter on my bluetooth keyboard, it works fine, I press enter and the keyboard seems to be paired to my MacBook, but when I try to press anything, it just doesn't work, nothing happens.

Sometimes, if I remove the keyboard and reconnect it again a lot of times, it would work for couple of minutes, but once i don't touch the keyboard for some time and it times out, it won't work again after it wakes up.

Anyone familiar with that issue?

Edit:

Console shows a lot of errors of this type:

> Couldn't read values in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x7fcd2e209be0> (Domain:
>   com.apple.Bluetooth, User: kCFPreferencesAnyUser, ByHost: Yes,
>   Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: Yes): accessing preferences
>   outside an application's container requires user-preference-read or
>   file-read-data sandbox access

and this type:

> rejecting read of { com.apple.Bluetooth, kCFPreferencesAnyUser,
>   kCFPreferencesCurrentHost, no container, managed: 0 } from process 52
>   because accessing preferences outside an application's container
>   requires user-preference-read or file-read-data sandbox access

Once I wake up the keyboard.

Comment: can you tell us what is going on in the console log

Comment: @Buscar웃 How do I check the console log?

Comment: @Buscar웃 Okay, nvm. Found it and updated the post

Comment: OK, let me take a look

Comment: lets start with Repairing your permissions as per https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203538

Comment: @Buscar웃 I did it. Still doesn't work and shows the same logs in Console.

Comment: ‘sandbox’. This defines exactly what they can and cannot do, and limits their access to resources such as preference files.

Comment: Install and run this app and see if it fixes your problem by changing the write/read for your Bluetooth  https://eclecticlightdotcom.files.wordpress.com/2018/08/permscan13.zip  Do not use it lavishly by changing them all, just the one making problems.

Comment: @Buscar웃 How do I use this program to change permissions? It only scans. Also, after it scanned, I tried looking for word 'bluetooth' inside the list of scanned folders and found nothing.

Comment: sorry, I can not replicate your problem on my Mac to help you.